# Laravel 5 How can I test scheduler call method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

I want to test a scheduler function through console. In `kernel.php`, I'm calling a controller function like:

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Administrator\CurrencyController@updatecurrencyDefault')->everyMinute();
```

From the post https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-55-task-scheduling-with-cron-job-example, I came to know that scheduler can be tested like:

```
php artisan CronJob:cronjob
```

But how can I test the scheduler with the `->call` method in the above example, via console?

Answer (score 1):

From this post [Configure and Test Laravel Task Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161679/configure-and-test-laravel-task-scheduling), I ran the command below and its all okay.

```
php artisan schedule:run
```