# Check if Task Scheduling works on local, Laravel

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-7

I am using Task Scheduling from Laravel, on local env. and till now I test it with `php artisan word:weeklyUpdate` , but I want to check if the Cron Job run automatically on a specific date, like in my code.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $scheduler = new LkpSchedulerUpdateDate;
    $scheduler = $scheduler->first()->toArray();

    $schedule->command('word:weeklyUpdate')->weeklyOn($scheduler->date, $scheduler->time);
    //ex: weeklyOn(3, 05:49:00)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure and Test Laravel Task Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161679/configure-and-test-laravel-task-scheduling)

Comment: I think those answers still apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813748/956397, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49051226/956397

Comment: Did you found any solution related to this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Create a schedule that runs just some minuts after the current time (let's say 5 minuts from now), wait, then check the results.

Edit:
It's because when you run `php artisan` word:weeklyUpdate` you execute the command directly.

The scheduled task your wrote is equivalent to execute `php artisan word:weeklyUpdate` in console every week.
Also, in your locale did you activated the cronJob scheduler?
`* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, but with php artisan word:weeklyUpdate it runs instantlly, even if I have everyFiveMinutes();