# Laravel 5 - Setting Kernel to run test script at regular intervals. (Cron job)

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel project, I have this file in my tests directory:

`tom_test.php`:

```
    <?php
        error_log("hello world");
```

I want to schedule this script to run every 'x' amount of time.
I've seen [this question from cyber8200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161679/configure-and-test-laravel-task-scheduling).
Unfortunately, I'm unsure how to make this test script to run.

Do I have to convert the test file to a class instead?

I would appreciate it if somebody would explicitly state what code needs to be added to the `app/Console/Kernel.php` file.
I suspect it should resemble some of the code in [the cyber8200 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161679/configure-and-test-laravel-task-scheduling)

## UPDATE

Thanks to [Tim Lewis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095402/laravel-5-setting-kernel-to-run-test-script-at-regular-intervals-cron-job#comment118597038_67095402), I've managed to get the cron job running (I think).

Unfortunately, I cannot see the "hello world" message being logged to the console.

Here is what I've done

I added a command as follows:

```
    public function handle()
    {
        error_log("hello");
//        echo base_path();
        exit;
        include base_path().'/tests/Browser/tom_test.php';
    }
```

and this schedule function to the kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('tom_test')
              ->everyMinute();
}
```

This is the result I get:
[image]

The job seems to be quitting after one run, and no message is logged to the console.

Comment: Laravel's Kernel can process Commands, so you'll need to make one (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#generating-commands) then call it via the Scheduler (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands), then setup a CRON task locally to run it (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler). Note: These docs are for Laravel 8, but it's a similar approach for Laravel 5.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I'm now able to get the command to run, but I can't see any output.
I will update the question

Comment: You should be able to do a simple `$this->error('Hello')` :) See the section on writing output: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-output. Also, if you need to easily test the command, don't run `php artisan scheduler:run`, just run the command directly via `php artisan {command:signature}` (replacing `{}` with your actual command). It looks like the output is being supressed by `> NUL 2 > &1`